# @deprecated since v1.10.0, please use {@link Keypair} instead

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, serum

I am trying to develope something on `Solana`, have taken an example from the web and trying to run it locally where the part in `Rust` seems to be fine. Due to runtime errors I am trying to type the `Javascript` part with `Typescript` and am stuck at the following snippet:

```
async function createMint(provider: serumCmn.Provider, authority: PublicKey) {
    if (authority === undefined) {
      authority = provider.wallet.publicKey;
    }
    const mint = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
    const instructions = await createMintInstructions(provider, authority, mint.publicKey);

    const tx = new anchor.web3.Transaction();
    tx.add(...instructions);

    await provider.send(tx, [mint]);

    return mint.publicKey;
  }
```

As you can notice, the `mint` variable is of type `anchor.web3.Keypair` but the method `provider.send` wants an `Account`, but the intereseting part is that at its definition I find `@deprecated since v1.10.0, please use {@link Keypair} instead`.

How can I fix it? How can I get an `Account` instead of the `Keypair`?

This is my `package.json`:

````
{
    "scripts": {
        "lint:fix": "prettier */*.js \"*/**/*{.js,.ts}\" -w",
        "lint": "prettier */*.js \"*/**/*{.js,.ts}\" --check"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@coral-xyz/anchor": "^0.29.0",
        "@project-serum/anchor": "^0.26.0",
        "@project-serum/common": "^0.0.1-beta.3",
        "@project-serum/serum": "^0.13.65"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/bn.js": "^5.1.0",
        "@types/chai": "^4.3.0",
        "@types/mocha": "^9.0.0",
        "chai": "^4.3.4",
        "mocha": "^9.0.3",
        "prettier": "^2.6.2",
        "ts-mocha": "^10.0.0",
        "typescript": "^4.3.5"
    }
}

```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue seems to be that you're mixing anchor code with some types from the old Serum version (v0.26) together with the up-to-date version by Coral (v0.29). Use only one of these at a time, I'd recommend the newest version by Coral.